# How to execute zsh script at logon which output will be visible in the terminal window?

Tags: macos, command-line, script, iterm, login

My default command line app is iTerm (version?) on macOS (version?).

I run my script at logon, (System Settings -> Login Items -> Open at Login + myStartScript.zsh) but the script output is not visible :-(

iTerm window pops out buy what is visible is the calling the script:

`/Users/user/myStartScript.zsh; exit`

After that I see that my .zshrc gets executed, which I really don't want to happen too.

Can I prevent .zshrc running and also have the output of myStartScript.zsh visible?

Answer (score 1):

To prevent `zsh` from reading any other startup file, except for `/etc/zshenv`, change the shebang in your script to-

```
#! /bin/zsh -f
```

The -f option is equivalent to the NO_RCS option.

Comment: ok, great, thanks, and what about being the output of myStartScrip.zsh file?

Comment: hmmm, I still see the .zshrc being executed...

Comment: `man -P "less -p RCS" zshoptions`